# No Margin on Last Children

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm aware of the '`:last-child`' pseudo selector in CSS, but what I want to do is remove the margin-bottom from the last child of each 'last' element in the div.

For example:

`<div id="box1" class="box">
        <div class="input-group"></div>
        <div class="input-group"></div>
        <div class="input-group"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="box2" class="box">
        <div class="input-group"></div>
        <div class="input-group"></div>
        <div class="input-group"></div>
    </div>`

So what I want to happen, is for each `.box`, I want the last `.input-group` to have no margin?

Now obviously `:last-child` will remove the margin-bottom from the immediate-last child of `.input-group`, but I want it to recognise when it's the last child of each `.box`, I'm not sure if I'm making sense here or not.

If that isn't possible, what other ways around it are there?

Cheers!
Mark

Answer (score 3):

`.input-group:last-child` should work without any changes.

```
.input-group:last-child{
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/F7W8p/2/

If you have other `.input-group` elements outside of `box` you can add `.box` to the selector:

```
.box .input-group:last-child{
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Here is an example showing the selector in action: http://jsfiddle.net/F7W8p/3/

Comment: hmm, your example worked but the same code never worked on my website

Comment: Is something overriding the styles?

Comment: Not from what I can see, I've got it like this:  

`div.input-group {
 margin: 17px 0;
}

div.input-group:first-child { margin-top: 0; }
div.input-group:last-child { margin-bottom: 0; }`

Comment: Could you put the entire HTML file in a github gist? The fiddle seems to work with your new css: http://jsfiddle.net/F7W8p/4/

Comment: @MarkEriksson. Your CSS files are likely being cached, empty your cache OR open in a less used browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
in your css document.

```
.box > .input-group:last-child {margin:0;}
```

Comment: What exactly does the `>` operator do in CSS?

Comment: It selects all, use this instead of having to define each element. since box repeats itself. the > will select all boxes and deal with the last-child of that box.

Comment: It means that `.box` would have to precede `.input-group` - at the uppermost layer. So if `.input-group` was wrapped in a `ul` for instance, it would not style it.

Comment: `.box .input-group:last-child {margin:0;}` or `.input-group:last-child {margin:0;}`  Will work too